# L4: populate multiple text inputs

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-4, populate

I'm working on an Laravel 4 project and we have an view with an dynamic form.

```
Form::text('title')
<ul>
    <li>Form::text('movie_actor[]')</li>
    <li>Form::text('movie_actor[]')</li>
    <li>Form::text('movie_actor[]')</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I've read that you need to set the validation for the multi fields to `array`. So I added the validation rules like so:

```
$v = Validator::make(Input::all(), array('title' => 'required', 'movie_actor' => 'array'));
```

When I enter some actors, leave the title empty and submit the form, then the user is redirected to the same page with:

```
return Redirect::route('movies.create')->withInput();
```

The problem is that I get the error `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.

The population works when I remove the actor inputs from the view or change the actor text fields to selects fields. But that is not what I want.

How can I populate the multi-text fields?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue too. I haven't figure out exactly why its happen but looks like those text input name should be "string" not array which means, you should do like follow:

```
<li>Form::text('movie_actor[0]')</li>
<li>Form::text('movie_actor[1]')</li>
<li>Form::text('movie_actor[2]')</li>
```

The differences are you need to manually add an index to those name array.